# Why does the execution jump to the (nested) else statement after exhausting the iterable in the for loop in following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

My Python 3.10.2 code goes through all matches played in a game (between two teams) and tries to find between them those with specific players on both sides. Code shortened/edited for readability:

```
team1, team2 = None, None
for players_in_a_match in list_of_matches:
    for nick, teamID in players_in_a_match:
            # we are iterating over single players
        if (team1 and team2) is None:
            # if the player is registered, we populate team1 and team2 to use in next iterations
            # lots of code omitted
            team1 = (team_name, team_id, team_position, list_of_player_nicks_in_the_team)
            # team2 = (same)
        else:
            # all iterations after the first one
            # checking if the player is in team1 / team2
            if nick in team1[3]:    # checking if player's part of first team
                continue
            elif nick in team2[3]:    # checking if player's part of second team
                continue
                # if the player is registered with one of teams, we continue
            # Note here
            else:
                team1, team2 = None, None
                break
                # if the player is not registered with either of teams, we can go to next match
    if (team1 and team2) is None:
        continue
        # go to next match
    # otherwise do some stuff with the match that we have confirmed to be between team1 and team2
```

Consider `list_of_matches = [[(Hugo, 1),(Albert, 2)]]`. Then following is expected:

1. First iteration, `nick = 'Hugo'`, `teamID = 1`. The code block `if (team1 and team2) is None:` is executed, populating both `team1, team2`. `team1[3] = ['Hugo']`, `team2[3] = ['Albert']`.
2. Second iteration, `nick = 'Albert'`, `teamID = 2`. The `else` block is executed, failing first `if nick in team1[3]:` check and executing the `if nick in team1[3]:` block - so `continue`.
3. Execution jumps to line `for nick, teamID in players_in_a_match:`, finds out the iterable is exhausted.
4. Execution jumps out of the inner loop to line `if (team1 and team2) is None:` at the bottom, failing the check and continuing on within the outer `for` loop, denoted here with the bottom comment `# otherwise do some stuff...`.

However, testing this out shows the execution goes as follows:

1. First iteration goes as described above.
2. Second iteration, we go to the `else` statement. We match the `elif` statement and `continue`. So far so good.
3. Execution jumps to second line in the code, the for loop. `players_in_a_match` iterable is exhausted. Still expected behaviour.
4. Execution jumps directly to the else block after the `# Note here` comment ???

I know there's a possibility to have an `else` block after `for` loop, which is used after the `for` loop iterable is exhausted. However, the `else` block here is nested within another `else` and part of another `if` block? Even the indentation doesn't match. What am I missing?

Comment: `if (team1 and team2) is None:` do you mean `if team1 is None and team2 is None:`?

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave us some actual data to work with.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman It's an odd way to write it, but it has the same effect as your code.

Comment: @JohnGordon No, it isn't. `(1 and None) is None == True` while `1 is None and None is None == False`.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Ahh.  I was only considering the case where they are both none.  Good catch.

Comment: You're initialising `team1` to something in the first iteration, never allowing the first `nick, teamID` pair to be checked against it. Your code has several odd choices like that. Please provide an example of data that demonstrates the problem, and describe what you expected to happen or as output instead.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman This is left over from previous versions of code where I had to make sure both teams are initialized before continuing, as it was possible that one was `None` and another wasn't.
If you're going for code clarity, I could now just check a single team, as they are at all times either both initialized or both `None`. Not sure how it related to my question though.

Comment: @Grismar I have edited the question to include more detailed expected execution steps.
The behaviour you're describing is intentional - I'm comparing a set of played matches to a set of special scheduled matches to see if any of the scheduled matches has been played already. In the first iteration, I have to check `nick, teamID` against all of the scheduled matches; if I find a scheduled match with that `nick`, then I just check all other `nick`s in the played match against `nick`s in the scheduled match (which are in  `team1, team2`). Hope this helps.

Comment: @NoiLess It's related because it shows intention and readability. I copied your code to try to help but there is a lot of stuff that complicates things. For example, why comment `# team2 = (same)` instead of writing the code? Anyone trying to run this code will not set both `team1` and `team2` as you write in point 2. They have to manually edit it. Also, in `team1 = (team_name, team_id, team_position, list_of_player_nicks_in_the_team)`, most are undefined (and is `team_id` same as `teamId` or different?) which forces us to guess and edit the code instead of you providing good example values.

Comment: These kinds of problems are easy to solve using a debugger, so I'd suggest you look up how to use it. As the question is currently, we can't help you as you haven't provided a [mre] which forces us to make too many guesses and spend an unnecessary amount of time.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I know how to use the debugger. I didn't want to copy the whole code as it's quite long and not easy to read, containing external libraries, calls etc. - however, that part of the code has been tested and works well. I was just trying to find what POSSIBLY could cause the `for` loop after exhausting the iterable to jump to an `else` statement that belongs to an `if` _inside of the for loop itself_, because I do not know about any behaviour in Python that would do that.  I will try to clean up the question with minimal info instead of whole context and post again. Thanks.

Comment: You're still not inluding any example data that actually demonstrates the problem you describe. You're caught in a typical "bad programmer" feedback loop where you're convinced there is some problem, and you're also convinced there shouldn't be - so you see no reason to step out of the box a try a few things that go against your conviction. People here are asking for example data so they can take your code and improve it based on a concrete example - however, you persist in describing why you think the code misbehaves. I'd bet a tidy sum the problem is your code with the data you're using.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, reproducible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)